# Rails can't get form to work - keep getting model_name error?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am trying to make it so that each of the todo items which has not been completed will be displayed in the list. At the end of the list I want a update button which will apply what is in each check box. Here is what I have:

```
            <ul class="list-group">
                <%= simple_form_for(@todos) do |f| %>
                    <% current_user.todoos.where(:done => false).each do |t| %>                         
                    <li class="list-group-item"><%= t.name %> <%= t.time %> <%= f.check_box :done, class: 'cbox' %></li>                
                <% end %>
              <%= f.button :submit, :label => 'Update', class: 'btn btn-md btn-primary' %>
            <% end %>
            </ul>
```

Comment: Can you give us the code for the whole form and the models?  It's really hard to tell what's going on from 8 lines of code, especially with the confusing todos/todoos naming.

Comment: Also, you'll get a lot more activity if you phrase your question to be more pointed.  Questions like "I have a problem" will not get answered.

Answer (score 1):

I think you have a typo in your code here:

```
<% current_user.todoos.where(:done => false).each do |t| %>
```

I'm assuming the correct form of this would be:

```
<% current_user.todos.where(:done => false).each do |t| %>
```

Comment: actually it is meant to be todoos (thats the model name). The problem comes from the  `<%= simple_form_for(@todos) do |f| %>` line somewhere